# iOS Smart App Banner - how to have banner return after hiding

Tags: ios, iphone, smartbanner

I have an iPhone on which I'm testing a new Smart App Banner (the meta tag that causes information about an app to appear above a webpage). At one point, I closed the banner to test what would happen, but now I'm unable to get the banner back. I'm sure it's still set up correctly because on other iPhones, it appears as normal. It seems this is simply something Safari does to prevent webpages from harassing you about it.

Unfortunately, even clearing Safari's cache didn't seem to bring back the banner. Does anyone have any ideas on what a tester can do to make Safari "forget" that you've already seen and dismissed a smart banner?

Comment: @WrightsCS Ah; yes, that question solves my problem nicely. It didn't come up in a search, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the smart banner back, clear your cookies.

Pressing the **x** stops the banner from re-appearing and I believe this is stored in the cookies.